# Error with Pig on Yarn - PigStatsUtil - Failed to get running job - IOException

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-yarn

I am hitting against this error on executing Pig jobs on top of Yarn. This error is not fatal though and the jobs seem to complete fine.

Just wanted to investigate this to see if some config is messed up. Did anyone else stumble upon this?

Have seen the same error on this Pig-User thread. Its still Unanswered:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pig-user/201308.mbox/%3CCA+HR8ZPo=64dx137eHMEaEJcG42ozvSk3LbTjyhmKasS23aBVw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Any tips would be appreciated.

```
    [main] WARN  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - Failed to get running job
java.io.IOException
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.invoke(ClientServiceDelegate.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobStatus(ClientServiceDelegate.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobStatus(YARNRunner.java:495)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getJob(Cluster.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:622)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJobUsingCluster(JobClient.java:622)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.getJob(JobClient.java:640)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(PigStatsUtil.java:345)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(PigStatsUtil.java:257)
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:324)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1266)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1251)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1241)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:335)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:137)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:475)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

Comment: Does this happen on certain nodes only?